# binding ng-click from the html rendered through jquery datatables wrapped inside Angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, datatables

I am using `jquery datatables` in my application to display the records. I have written an angularjs custom directive to wrap the `jquery-datatable`. Notice that I am generating the html code to render the 'checkbox' through the jquery-datatable function.

Below is my directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
 .directive('iDataGrid', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/iDataGrid/iDataGrid.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$watch('newHosts', function(){
        var table=$('#dataTables-example').dataTable( {
          "jQueryUI": true,
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
          "aaData": scope.newHosts,
          "bFilter": true,
          "oSearch": {"bRegex":true, "bSmart": false},
          "destroy": true,
          "aoColumns": [
              { "mData": " " },
              { "mData": "name" },
              { "mData": "age" },
              { "mData": "location" },
              { "mData": "environment" },
              { "mData": "changes_summary"}
          ],
          "aoColumnDefs": [
              {
                "aTargets": [ 0 ],
                "mRender" : function(data,type,full) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" id="user_id" name=username"
                     onclick="clickhandle(\''+full.user_Id+'\', \''+full.name+'\');"/>';
                }
              }
           ]
        });
        var table = $('#dataTables-example').dataTable();
       }
     );
    }
    };
});
```

The template to load the data (template pointing to - iDataGrid.html):

```
<table id ="dataTables-example"  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th># Changes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In my html file I using the directive:
   `<i-data-grid></i-data-grid>`

Now when I select the checkbox in my browser, I am not able to handle the `ng-click`event in my directive and also the controller.

Could someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: May be you can use isolated scope for your directive. Check this short videotutorial (https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope) about isolated scope. It shows an example of attaching events to templates returned inside a directive. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi. I tried using the `isolate scope` but I am using the `scope` to bind the data to the `aaData` attribute and also watching on a scope value `newHosts`. Is there any other way to handle this?